# LC-3 programming finding the corresponding location of the first "1" in a number

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am having trouble implementing this into assembly language. I don't understand the logic of it.

Let's say I have a number b0100000000000001, the first significant bit is 14.

```
.ORIG x3000
ld    r0, number      ;address of the number in r0

number .fill b0100000000000001      ;allocates the number to r0
```

So after I have stored the number in r0, I have to loop through the number and find the corresponding 1? How would I do this in assembly language.

edit: this is what i have now, is this correct?

```
    .ORIG   x3000
LEA  R0, NUMBER     ;address of the number into R0
LOOP BRz finish
     ADD R1, R1, #1

finish  HALT






NUMBER  .fill   b0100000000000001   ;allocates number to r0
.END
```

Comment: You'll need to check each bit in a loop. LC-3 has a limited assembly language, but helpful instructions will be `AND` (bitwise "and") and one of the conditional branches (such as branch if zero). You need a way to generate consecutive bit positions to test (`b01`, `b010`, `b0100`...) ...so you can put those in a table, or construct them by starting with `b01` and then continually adding it to itself (which shifts it left one bit).

Comment: To check if it is 0, do I use BRz? Also, I will need to use `ADD` to shift to the left? But why do I have to shift it to the left? Shouldn't I shift to the right to get the next character in the number

Comment: Yes you could use BRz. You would shift left if you start at the low bit. Start high bit and shift right would be more effective if you had a wider variety of instructions to support doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop currently isn't checking anything. You have the number go into the loop and immediately jump to finish because it is a non zero number.

You're going to have to AND your number with some sort of mask to check for the first occurring one.

Say you had the number 010001010
 and you AND it with 10000000
 it would give you 00000000 or zero so you know the first bit is also zero,

but if you try 01000000 then it will give you 010000000 so you know the first one occurs in the second place.

Make this some sort of loop and count how many times it takes you to get to the first 1.